# Cannot abort superagent in React app

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, coffeescript, superagent

I am refactoring some code in a React app I've built to make ajax requests to the Tumblr api with [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) instead of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Note that when using coffeescript @ is equivalent to 'this'.

My jQuery ajax call to the tumblr api is as follows:

```
App = React.createClass

  loadPhotos: ->

    data =
      api_key: 'xxx'

    blog = 'tumblrname'
    url = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/#{blog}.tumblr.com/posts/photo"


    @xhr = $.ajax
      url: url
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'jsonp'
      data: data
      success: (data) =>   

        console.log @xhr, @
```

The console output for this is:

`Object {readyState: 4, responseJSON: Object, status: 200, statusText: "load"} Constructor {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, state: Object…}`

Everything works correctly when I am using jQuery and I am able to call @xhr.abort() to abort the ajax call.

However when I switch to using superagent the call is made successfully and I can access the response data, however I can't access the @xhr variable to abort the request.

My superagent ajax call:

```
superagent = require 'superagent'
jsonp = require 'superagent-jsonp'

App = React.createClass

  loadPhotos: ->

    data =
      api_key: 'xxx'

    blog = 'tumblrname'
    url = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/#{blog}.tumblr.com/posts/photo"


    @xhr = superagent
      .get url 
      .use jsonp
      .query data 
      .end (err, res) =>

        console.log @xhr, @
```

The console output for this code is:

`undefined Constructor {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, state: Object…}`

If I change the superagent .end to use -> instead of => console.log(this) returns:

`Request {_query: Array[2], method: "GET", url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged", header: Object, _header: Object…}`

Which is what I need to call .abort() on to abort the ajax call. Unfortunately I need to use a fat arrow to be able to use this.state when performing manipulations on the response data.

My question is: why is @xhr returning undefined when I use superagent instead of jQuery, and how can I update my code to allow access to @xhr so I can call .abort() on it as needed?

Comment: how about `self = this`.. forget if you can't do that in cs for some reason

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting? There's no reason to set self = this that I can think of, the fat arrow already does that for me. I need access to the this.xhr variable as well as the this.state variables within the superagent response function. I have access to this.state because of the fat arrow but not this.xhr.

Comment: Write `self = this` somewhere in the method so you have access to `self.state` then use thin arrow in `end` to get access `this.abort`

Comment: Ah ok gotcha, got this working with a little bit of modification. Will post my answer and the code in a second. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @azium mentioned, the way I solved this was to use `self = this` and then set `@xhr` within the superagent `.end()` function. I also refactored the data manipulation into another function `processResponse()`. The working code is below:

```
superagent = require 'superagent'
jsonp = require 'superagent-jsonp'

App = React.createClass

  loadPhotos: ->

    self = @ 

    data =
      api_key: 'xxx'

    blog = 'tumblrname'
    url = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/#{blog}.tumblr.com/posts/photo"

    req = superagent
      .get url 
      .use jsonp
      .query data 
      .end (err, res) ->

        self.xhr = @

        self.processResponse(res.body)

  processResponse: (data) ->
    # do the stuff to the response data with @state
```